# SQLiteDatabase rawQuery hangs

Tags: android, sqlite, locking, android-sqlite

I've created an Android IntentService that downloads data from a remote server and stores in a SQLiteDatabase. When I run the service the first time everything runs perfectly but the second time I try to run it ends up hanging and I'm not too sure why.

```
c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM abc WHERE def = ? AND ghi = 1", new String[]{Integer.toString(uid)});
```

It's this line where it hangs so I've a feeling it's something to do with the database being locked and it's wait for it to unlock but I could be totally wrong. I had previously been getting locking exceptions but they appear to have gone. It's nothing to do with the query take a while to execute because normally it executes instantly and I've waited 5 minutes on the second run and it is still hanging

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

Context context;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 10);
    this.context = context;
}

public SQLiteDatabase getDB() {
    if ((mDatabase == null) || (!mDatabase.isOpen())) {
        mDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    return mDatabase;
}
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

public static DatabaseHelper helper;
public static SQLiteDatabase database;


public MyApplication() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    helper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate();
    if (database != null && database.isOpen()) {
        database.close();
    }
}

}
```

All database access is done using the one database object in MyApplication.
Any insight into the query hanging would be appreciated.

**Logcat**

```
The connection pool for database '/data/data/abc/databases/def.sqlite' has been unable to grant a connection to thread 1897 (IntentService[SyncService]) with flags 0x1 for 270.01202 seconds.
```

Comment: Dumb question but, have you tried closing your cursor? Like `c.close()` after you're done with your query.

Comment: why dont you retrieve db by calling helper.getDB()?

Comment: Any messages in your logcat?

Comment: @ThyenHongGuedesChang Ya I've closed all the cursors after using them.

Comment: @IvanSkoric I can try using that but I think its all the same

Comment: @Buddy unfortunately the Logcat is no help in this case.

Comment: @Buddy there was some stuff in the logcat so I've updated the question

Comment: @DanielNugent The only place it's called is in MyApplication and the same database object is then used everywhere

Comment: Add your code that gets the db reference in the IntentService.

Comment: When you update the local DB, are you using beginTransaction?  Is there a path where you're not calling endTransaction?

Comment: how did you solve this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it ended up being an unclosed transaction that caused the problem!